# Scala: Reuse Function Value

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have these 2 functions:

```
  1)
  protected def withBagAsync(body: Bag => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
  //... implementation
  }

  2)
  protected def withBag(body: Bag => Result): Future[Result] =
     withBagAsync(body??)
```

I want to reuse the functionality of `1` from `2`.

But I can not figure out how to do that.

Comment: Could you please provide some more implementation details of the methods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward implementation would be something like this:

```
def withBag(body: Bag => Result): Future[Result] =
  withBagAsync(bag => Future.successful(body(bag))
```

Or, more or less equivalently:

```
def withBag(body: Bag => Result): Future[Result] =
  withBagAsync(body.andThen(Future.successful))
```

You need to transform a `Bag => Result` into a `Bag => Future[Result]`, and the simplest way to do that is to compose your given `Bag => Result` and a `Result => Future[Result` function, and `Future.successful` is a `A => Future[A]` function that just wraps the argument in a successful future.

If the `body` argument to `withBag` can fail with an exception, or if you need it to be executed in another thread, etc., you might want something like this instead:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

def withBag(body: Bag => Result)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Result] =
  withBagAsync(bag => Future(body(bag)))
```

Now the caller can either implicitly or explicitly provide an execution context, and any exceptions thrown by `body(bag)` will be captured in a failed future.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach to dealing with this, is to make the `withBagAsync` method believe that it is receiveing a function rather than a value and a simple solution for that is to make the call as

```
protected def withBag(body: Bag => Result): Future[Result] =
  {
    val function: Bag => Future[Result] = (body: Bag) => Future.successful(Result())

    withBagAsync(function)
  }
```